# login system not working using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

so im trying to get my login working which is using php and mysql. i dont no what to replace (mysqli_fetch_array) because before i was using md5 password and changed it to password hash. what i want the code to basically do is when the users correct email and password is inputted the page is redirected to (user-page.php) where the user info will be displayed. im only having problems with the login as the register is working with password hash

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once "connection.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])!="") {
    header("Location: user-page.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
    }

 $query = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?";

   if(!empty($query)){
           if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
               $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['uid'];
               $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['full_name'] = $row['full_name'];
               $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
               $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender'];
                $_SESSION['medical_condition'] = $row['medical_condition'];
               header("Location: user-page.php");
           }
       }else {

           }
       }


?>
```

the below code works by checking if the email exits and if the password is correct but only displays if the password is correct or incorrect. is there a way to redirect the user like the code above?

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once "connection.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])!="") {
    header("Location: user-page.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
    }

 $query = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?";
 $params = array($_POST['email']);
    $results = dataQuery($query, $params);

    $hash = $results[0]['password']; // first and only row if username exists;

    echo password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash) ? 'password correct' : 'passwword incorrect';
           }



?>
```

register.php

```
<?php
    require('connection.php');

    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $medical_condition = $_POST['medical_condition'];
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //  insert values into the database.
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `full_name`, `gender`,`email`,`medical_condition`, `password`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)';
        $params = array($username, $full_name, $gender, $email, $medical_condition, $password);

        $result = dataQuery($query, $params);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['full_name'] = $full_name;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
        $_SESSION['medical_condition'] = $medical_condition;
        if($result){
                   header("Location: user-page.php");
                }
            }else{

?>
```

Comment: What is the `?` in your `SELECT` statement? You're not using a prepared statement, so it's being interpreted literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When login in, after you check if password is valid, you need to fill your Session the same way you would after registering.

It differs from the registering, Instead of receiving all the information via the $_POST attribute, you need to get the information from the database and fill the $_SESSION.

So you would need to select more information from the query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?";
$params = array($_POST['email']);
$results = dataQuery($query, $params);

$hash = $results[0]['password']; // first and only row if username exists;

if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash) )
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $results[0]['username'];
    $_SESSION['full_name'] = $results[0]['full_name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $results[0]['email'];
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $results[0]['gender'];
    $_SESSION['medical_condition'] = $results[0]['medical_condition'];
    header("Location: user-page.php");
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear, I was way off track with my other solution. That thing where the session is not transmitted and requiring to add it manually is when PHP can't store cookies in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, you're trying to do a redirect with `header("Location: user-page.php");` after doing `password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash)` and storing your user information in `$_SESSION`.

There is a single issue when using `header()` function as stated in the documentation :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Note:
>
> Session ID is not passed with Location header even if session.use_trans_sid is enabled. It must by passed manually using SID constant.

So you have to actually add the Session ID to the url manually for your session to persist to your next page.

It would look like this:

```
//https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php
//https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id 
// 
//EDIT:
//307 Temporary Redirect
//Added slash "/" in front of php page. Better browser recognition.
header("Location: /user-page.php?".htmlspecialchars(SID),TRUE, 307);
//Use exit function to terminate program and make sure it does not perform any other tasks.
exit();
```

Comment: the redirect to the user page works but the information is not being displayed that's the problem. and for the register i basically did the same Method as the login just without the if

Comment: your talking about the 1st or 2nd code sample i posted?

Comment: i added my register.php to the question

Comment: How are you displaying the information on the user-page.php? Because that seems to be the issue. user-page.php needs to have it's own session_start(); as to resume the session.

Comment: so i added the code for user-page.php. the register works perfectly after the user creates a new account they are redirected to the user-page.php and all the information in displayed. i want to do something slimier with the login

Comment: Everytime you use the function header you have to concatenate the Session ID to the address. Did you try that?  header("Location: login.php?"+htmlspecialchars(SID)); adapt to fit the location.

Comment: im adding: header("Location: user-page.php?"+htmlspecialchars(SID)); at the end of the 2nd code sample i posted but noting is redirecting

Comment: I updated the code for the header function it will make browser better understand the HTTP Header for redirection.

Comment: i did the header like you did but its telling me object not found

Comment: If you go back to your initial solution.  Does it work when you register? After registering, does the user-page.php show the user information?

Comment: yep register works fine. the user inputs the information and is redirected to the user-page.php with all the user info displayed

Comment: the login was working before but since i added password hash to the register i needed to change some things

Comment: My current thought is that your session was still filled from the registering and when you logged in, it was still using the previous session. If you closed your browser, the session would have cleared then login would have an empty session maybe? See my other answer for this train of thought

Comment: i have a logout button which destroys the session